# jScrollPane inboc style read more with show more details on hover

Tags: jquery, jscrollpane

here is a simple example of what I am trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/TUjM5/1/

So that on hover of the message this shows extra details and then reinitialise jscroll.

How can I set it so that on scroll using the mouse it doesn't try to show the messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the api. It's in the [documentation](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/api.html)

Here's what you need to do

```
var element = $('.scroll-pane').jScrollPane();
var data = element.data('jsp');

$('.scroll-pane li').hover(function(){
    $(this).find(".hide").slideDown();
    data.reinitialise();
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUjM5/2/)